# Django with postgres backend attribute error

Tags: arrays, django, python-3.x, django-models, postgresql-11

**SOLVED**
Currently I am working on my first django project. The DB is modeling the structure of an Abaqus input file. Here is the Code

```
from django.db import models as m
import django.contrib.postgres as pg

class node(m.Model):
    inputfile = m.CharField(max_length = 255)
    source_id = m.IntegerField()
    source_sim = m.CharField(max_length = 255)
    coordinates = pg.fields.ArrayField(m.FloatField(), size = 3)
```

When I call `manage.py makemigrations` (Or just python) it gives me the error message:

```
 AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.postgres' has no attribute 'fields'
```

When I import ArrayField in a testscript, it works:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models as m

a = ArrayField(m.FloatField(), size=3)
print(a)

>>><django.contrib.postgres.fields.array.ArrayField>
```

I was able to migrate my classes into a TestDB without the ArrayField.
My Python version 3.7.1, my Django version is 2.1.3

What's my mistake?

edit: Style&formatting. Thanks to suggestions.
Edit: Solved, but cant find how to flag that

Comment: This is basic python: as the error says, `fields` isn't an attribute so you have to do as you did on the command-line: `from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField` or `import django.contrib.postgres.fields as pg_fields` and then `pg_fields.ArrayField` will work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked...